# This code should simply read a file containing dates and save them in an array of structs, but when i control print i get strange result

Tags: c, date

here i define a simple struct date, that should contain the elements of a file of this type
( i don't translate the string, they are just an other language for the names of the month, ottobre is october, quite intuitive)

```
20 ottobre 1998
1 dicembre 2029
22 gennaio 2002
5 gennaio 1999
```

the only function is the Read_File function that should save in a pointer a list of dates and in the meantime convert the strings month into integers for simplicity.
when i control print the day of each element i don't get absolutely any output

how do i fix this simple brief code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>



struct date {
    int day, month, year;

};


struct date *Read_File(FILE *f, int *n)
{
    struct date *v;
    int dim = 4;
    char buf[250];
    char month[20];

    if (!(v = malloc(dim * sizeof(struct date))))
        return NULL;
    

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(struct date), f) != NULL) {

        if (3 != sscanf(buf, "%d %s %d", 
                &v[*n].day,  month, &v[*n].year))
            continue;

        if (!(strcmp(month, "gennaio")))
            v[*n].month = 0;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "febbraio")))
            v[*n].month = 1;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "marzo")))
            v[*n].month = 2;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "aprile")))
            v[*n].month = 3;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "maggio")))
            v[*n].month = 4;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "giugno")))
            v[*n].month = 5;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "luglio")))
            v[*n].month = 6;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "agosto")))
            v[*n].month = 7;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "settembre")))
            v[*n].month = 8;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "ottobre")))
            v[*n].month = 9;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "novembre")))
            v[*n].month = 10;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "dicembre")))
            v[*n].month = 11;
        printf("\n%d\n", v[*n].day);

        (*n) =(*n)+3;
        
        if (dim == (*n)) {
            dim *= 2;
            if (!(v = realloc(v, dim * sizeof(struct date))))
                return 0;
        }
    }
    v = realloc(v, (*n) * sizeof(struct date));
    return v;
}




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *f;
    struct date *v;
    int n = 0;
    int i;
    int colours[7] = { 0 };

    if (!(f = fopen(argv[1], "r")))
        return 0;

    if (!(v = Read_File(f, &n)))
        return 0;
    fclose(f);



    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%dx%d\n", v[i].day, v[i].year);
    
    
    free(v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `(*n) =(*n)+3`? Adding just one should be enough. You are just going to the next entry of the `v` array.

Comment: Inside `Read_File()`, the variable `*n` is initially `0`... you add `3` to it (possibly several times), making it `3`, `6`, ... and you eventually compare it to `dim` which is `4`. `*n` will never equal `dim`.

Comment: oh you are right i fixed it. now, but i still don't get any output

Comment: Time to learn how to use a *debugger*. With a debugger you can step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values and see how the values change.

Comment: i will definitely learn how to use debugger soon

Comment: @TommasoCashmoney did you see my answer also speaking about other problems ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your program

First

> ```
> while (fgets(buf, sizeof(struct date), f) != NULL) {
> ```

must be

```
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f) != NULL) {
```

in your case you can be not able to read enough characters on each line and then `sscanf` cannot extract the tree elements and does not return 3 as expected

Second

> ```
> (*n) =(*n)+3;
> ```

can be

```
(*n) =(*n)+1;
```

because you read only one new entry rather than three

After these changes, compilation  and execution :

```
/tmp % gcc -g -Wall c.c
c.c: In function 'main':
c.c:78:9: warning: unused variable 'colours' [-Wunused-variable]
     int colours[7] = { 0 };
         ^
/tmp % cat f
20 ottobre 1998
1 dicembre 2029
22 gennaio 2002
5 gennaio 1999
/tmp % ./a.out f

20

1

22

5
20x1998
1x2029
22x2002
5x1999
/tmp %
```

Notice the useless variable indicated by the compiler

Probably also you do not wanted

> ```
> printf("\n%d\n", v[*n].day);
> ```

but

```
printf("\n%d\n", v[*n].month);
```

just after you set the month number, and because in *main* you only output the day and year, or of course just remove that line and also output the month in *main*